# Count rows with 2 different Date-time columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I have a Dataframe with 2 date columns as:

```
 ---------------------------- 
| date_created |  date_ended |
|--------------| ----------- |
|20/12/01      | 20/11/01    |
|20/12/01      | 20/12/02    |
|20/12/02      | 20/12/02    |
|20/12/02      | 20/12/03    |
|20/12/02      | 20/12/03    |
|20/12/03      | 20/12/03    |
|20/12/03      | 20/12/04    |
 ----------------------------
```

I need to count the rows from both columns when both column values(dates) are same, i.e. the output I need:

```
 ------------------------------------------
| date_index   |created_count| ended_count |
|--------------| ----------- | ----------- |
|20/11/01      |      0      |      1      |
|20/12/01      |      2      |      0      |
|20/12/02      |      3      |      2      |
|20/12/03      |      2      |      3      |
|20/12/04      |      0      |      1      |
 ------------------------------------------
```

I had been counting individual columns one by one and then matching with same date index. Is there any clean way to achieve this? If anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), replace non match NaNs to `0` and last convert to integers:

```
df = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
         date_created  date_ended
20/11/01             0           1
20/12/01             2           0
20/12/02             3           2
20/12/03             2           3
20/12/04             0           1
```

If want filter columns for processing:

```
cols = ['date_created','date_ended']
df = df[cols].apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)

          date_created  date_ended
20/11/01             0           1
20/12/01             2           0
20/12/02             3           2
20/12/03             2           3
20/12/04             0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
res = pd.concat((df['date_created'].value_counts(),
                 df['date_ended'].value_counts()),
                  axis=1, sort=True).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
          date_created  date_ended
20/11/01             0           1
20/12/01             2           0
20/12/02             3           2
20/12/03             2           3
20/12/04             0           1
```